# How to log-out Spring Security in Vaadin?

Tags: spring-security, vaadin, logout

Is there a practical working example of how to **programmatically** log out from Spring Security? I tried many ways, and no one works; the session ID stays valid in the browser.

Here is the code I am using:

```
activeUserMenu.addItem("Log out", e -> {
        UI.getCurrent().getPage().setLocation("/");
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler = new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
        logoutHandler.logout(
            VaadinServletRequest.getCurrent().getHttpServletRequest(), null,
            null);
        for(Cookie cookie : VaadinServletRequest.getCurrent().getCookies()) {
          cookie.setMaxAge(0);
        }
      });
```

Notice: I log in through a custom Thymeleaf form. In theory, all I have to do is redirect the browser to "/logout" default Spring URL. But Vaadin tells me that the router does not recognize that URL. I made several other attempts, including using Javascript and handling a get to "/logout". None worked.

Comment: You seem to be doing it right as far as I know. You could try this on top of what you already are doing https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-application-lifecycle/#application.lifecycle.session-closing

Comment: I also tried closing the session, the same result. I suspect the cause I am mixing Vaadin and Thymeleaf, and, ironically, I only use Thymeleaf for the login form because the same form embedded in a Vaadin page does not work.

Comment: I do not know how you experience not being logged out successfully but I will ask. Unless you know, could it be that Vaadin heartbeats is throwing you of? You can remedy this by waiting some time (3 x timeout value i believe) and try to verify logout after this. Also I will recommend you to ask on Vaadin Discord channel in case none of the Vaadin experts have seen this question.

Comment: Thanks, Avec, I believe you are on the right track. In fact, I see a short flash in "Development tools" in which everything is reset then everything comes back. Unhappily I was a little new to Vaadin, and I did not know about "Discord channel". I think it is too late now. I could try with their login form but my pro subscription expired on Dec/31. Should one day I renew it I will further explore the issue. Once again thank you to everybody for providing help.

Comment: You are welcome. Unless you must use commercial components there is now need for pro license. The discord channel is for all users and does not require a Vaadin user. Check out https://discord.gg/vaadin

Comment: Thanks again Avec. I would need a commercial license to enable authentication without recurring to Thymeleaf. I suspect it is not a Vaadin issue, but it is caused by using Vaadin with MVC. I had a commercial license and used the login form component, but I needed a remember-me button, so I switched to Thymeleaf for login. I know that you can build a custom Vaadin, but I am not skilled enough. In the meantime, my license went over, and deadlines forced me now to alternative frameworks. Good to know about discord group for eventual future Vaadin projects.

Answer (score 2):

Configure:

```
http.
...
.logout()
.logoutUrl("/logout")
.invalidateHttpSession(true)
.deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
```

then

```
logoutButton.addClickListener(clickEvent -> {
            UI.getCurrent().getPage().setLocation("/logout");
        });
```

Comment: After Vaadin V 23, I do not use Thymeleaf anymore (just pure Vaadin) so I am unable to try the provided code, but I will test it with Open-ID connect next week.

Comment: @FrancoG any success since May 2022 ?  :D

Comment: Hi Enver. No luck, unfortunately. I finally gave up and rewrote the whole application as MVC (Thymeleaf). The application had to undergo a corporate pentest and I had to avoid risks. Surely not same quality and interactivity, but I had to bill it.

Answer (score 0):

I think clearing cookies should work. I use the following to remove a cookie by name in a Vaadin 14 app:

```
private void removeCookie(String cookieName) {
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, "");
    cookie.setMaxAge(0);
    VaadinResponse.getCurrent().addCookie(cookie);
}
```

Alternatively you should be able to logout just by invalidating the whole HTTP session:
`VaadinServletRequest.getCurrent().getHttpServletRequest().getSession().invalidate()`

Comment: It doesn't work. If you look at my code I am already doing it.

Comment: You are missing `addCookie(cookie)`, but also session invalidation should work as as simple solution.

Comment: Agree. You are setting cookies to blank, but I've always invalidated cookies setting maxAge to 0, and it has always worked on all browsers. Further VaadinServletRequest.getCurrent() already invalidates the session (I also already tried to invalidate once more - no results). If I watch Developer tools, I see all that happens, but in a flash after that, everything comes back. I think that Avec is on the right track; something (maybe heartbeat) revalidates everything after I clear.

Comment: Hmm... heartbeat should not keep http sessions alive, if there are none, but that left me thinking that close should actually happen one level higher. I guess you already tried `UI.getCurrent().getSession().close()` ?

Comment: Hi eeq, thanks; yep, I already tried. I am almost sure it is not a Vaadin issue but something related to the MVC pages I added with Thymeleaf but I am unable to authenticate with pure Vaadin.

Comment: Getting interesting. Are there JWT tokens involved or something like that? Anyway, let us know when you find it.

Comment: Yes, security is managed through JWT tokens. I will make one more attempt to remove MVC (Thymeleaf) that I believe the villain using a form embedded in Vaadin (the for some other weird reason does not work).